# return parameters from swf/exe to commandline

Tags: flash, apache-flex, command-line, air, return-value

I need to create flash/flex/AIR application which will run from command line.
This application will take parameters from command line, process this data and return some data back to command line.
Passing parameters to exe/swf is fine but how to return data to command line?

Is there any way to print/display trace output to command line?

Comment: My suspicion is that AIR is not the best platform for something like this.